# Is there a google pay webhook?

Tags: google-pay

Prototyping a Loyalty Card website. As per the info on https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/ 
Seems polling is the only option on status/managing the Cards.

Is there a google pay webhook? That would provide notifications for: 
A user has added the card to their wallet.**
A user has removed the card from their wallet.

** One way is to use the success-handler when rendering the save to pay button.

Comment: A webhook like receiving custom parameters? Anybody can answer? I am also looking for this feature.